# why is Pyspark joined column turning into null values?

Tags: python, pyspark, left-join

I'm trying to join two dataframes but the values of the second keep turning into nulls:

```
joint = sdf.join(k, "date", how='left').select(sdf.date, sdf.Res, sdf.Ind, k.gen.cast(IntegerType())).orderBy('date')
```

output:  `| 1/1/2001 |  4103 | 9223 | null |`

Comment: may be there is no matching date value in k and due to that, it is returning null. As you are using left join, you will be getting null from the right table, if there is no matching value in the right table.

Comment: That's what I thought at first, but k.show() shows it's full of data.

Comment: that is fine. but, does k have dates of sdf, as it is being used as key. E.g, does k have dates for 1/1/2001 ?

Comment: Yes, both have the same date range, the only difference is k originally had a 00:00:00 time stamp so I reformatted to match yyyy/mm/dd of sdf.

Comment: Please try to provide a [mcve] with a small [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427185/how-to-make-good-reproducible-apache-spark-examples). My guess is that `k.gen` is failing the conversion to integer, but there's no way to tell without seeing the data.